# Is this site the right one to get a review to a mathematical solution?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

There are a lot of mathematically books with exercises / experiments which do not provide a (detailed) solution.

Is it 'allowed' to show my solution and ask the users if it is correct or not?

E.g. Sawyers 'Mathematic's Delight' gives some exercises but no solutions, yet it'll be helpful to know if my way of thinking was 'right'.

('this site' does not mean meta :) )

Comment: This is stating the obvious, but one thing to keep in mind is to be as clear and concise as you can for the parts you want people to proofread :) Long or convoluted posts tend to frustrate a segment of the readers, but a long post that is clearly written will be received well. Glad to hear you're taking this approach to getting feedback: I'm sure you'll learn a lot this way!

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, we even [have a tag for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification).

---

Please, however, make sure you include the entirety of the question statement. Sometimes the other users may ask you for further clarifications (such as definitions used etc.) It would also not hurt to include the name of the book and its author to make it more searchable for future visitors.

Comment: Great, thanks. Didn't thought about looking at the tags at all :)